# How can i encode the url while form submission %5B%5D using get method php

Tags: php, urlencode

I'm using multi country search using get method php. In my first page i'm using this code for ex:   `<select id="country" name="nationality[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">`

In my result page the url is encoded as: `url?name=Ganesh&nationality%5B%5D=Italian&nationality%5B%5D=French`

```
if(isset($_GET['nationality'])) {
    $are='all';

    if($_GET['nationality']!=$are) {

        $loc = $_GET['nationality'];
        $nationality = array($loc);

        $comma_separated = implode(",", $nationality);

        $items = preg_split("/[,\\t]+/", $comma_separated);
        $sqlItems = array();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $sqlItems []= "'" . ($item). "'";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have? `$_GET['nationality']` is already an array (when at least one element is selected). Why do you use `implode()` and then immediately do `preg_split()` again? What are you trying to do? Do a `var_dump($_GET['nationality']);` to see what you get from the browser.

Comment: It shows echo var_dump($_GET['nationality']);     ------------->     string(7) "Italian"

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be tested by others. It should show the full PHP script and the full HTML form. Also add a `var_dump($_GET);` for debugging purposes to see the values coming in.